# Matlab:Xcorr operation without using for loops

Tags: matlab, correlation

I have two matrices A(2*1600*3) and B(2*1600). I am trying to do xcorr operation for each row in A against each row in B and want to store the  results in a Matrix. At present I am using the following code.

```
for ii=1:3
    for jj=1:2
       X(ii,jj)=max((xcorr(A(jj,:,ii),B(jj,:)))); 
    end
end
```

Since I am using two for loops, it is consuming more time and is affecting the execution time of my entire program which already had a for loop. How can I do this without the two for loops and store the output in a matrix ?

Meanwhile, I have also tried the above code with cellfun for a single column of the output matrix.

```
`cellfun(@(x) max(xcorr(x, B(1,:))), A, 'UniformOutput', false);`
```

In my observation, for loop is much faster than  cellfun.
Execution times:
 For loop: 2.4 secs for two columns of matrix output. Cellfun:2.6 secs for one column of matrix output.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily using `fft`.  Cross-correlation is very similar to convolution:

```
% Compute the size of the cross-correlation.
N = size(A,2) + size(B,2) - 1;
% Do correlation using FFT.  We have to flip one of the inputs.
% If A and B are both symmetric, you might want to add the 'symmetric' flag to ifft
Y = ifft(fft(A,N,2) .* fft(flip(B,2),N,2), N, 2);
% Squeeze out the second dimension and transpose so it matches your size and shape.
Y = squeeze(max(Y, [], 2))'
```

Comment: Hi Sardar,   Thanks for your reply, Since the Dimesnions of matrices A & B are not the same, so it also needs a for loop.

Comment: Yes, this example used the implicit scalar expansion of R2016b.  If you have an earlier version of MATLAB, you can use `bsxfun` instead in the second line: `Y = ifft(bsxfun(@times, fft(A,N,2) fft(flip(B,2),N,2), N, 2));`

Comment: Hi CKT, I am getting the following error message while I try to execute the above command,"Undefined function 'fft' for input arguments of type 'cell'".

Comment: Hi CKT, My bad I have used wrong values for A and B. Anyhow, The above line is not working . you missed out a comma after first fft and also the second fft is not consistent.

Comment: Sorry; that should have read `Y = ifft(bsxfun(@times, fft(A,N,2), fft(flip(B,2),N,2)), N, 2);`.  And again, this assuming that `size(A) = [ 2 1600 3 ]` and `size(B) = [ 2 1600 ]`.

Comment: Hi CKT, i have used this Y=max(ifft((bsxfun(@times,fft(A,N,2),conj(fft(B(1,:),N)))),N,2),[],2). Its taking too much time than the two methods which i mentioned in my question,

Comment: I don't see why you are taking only one row of B.  This isn't the same as the original question.  If you want to remove all of the loops and get an equivalent result to your original code, then you can use the suggestion above.  If it's not faster, then there's no point in removing the loops anyway.